# Serialize Delphi TDictionary to JSON string as C#

Tags: json, delphi, generics, serialization, tdictionary

I have a **Delphi** program written in Alexandria 11.1 that needs to send a **JSON file** to a service that is written in **C#**. If the JSON structure is static, I create a model class and use the native `TJson.ObjectToJsonString` of `REST.Json` to convert it to JSON string.

For example, a static **JSON** like:

```json
{
    "pair1": "value1",
    "pair2": "value2",
    "array": [
        {
            "PairString": "1",
            "PairInt": 1
        },
        {
            "PairString": "2",
            "PairInt": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

This is implemented with a **Delphi** class like:

```pascal
  TMyItem = class
  public
    PairString: string;
    PairInt: Integer;
  end;
  
  TExample = class
  public
    pair1: string;
    pair1: string;
    array: TArray<TMyItem>; 
  end;
```

How can I create a similar model for a dynamic set of pairs? Is it possible in that way?

For example, a JSON like:

```json
{
    "dictionary": {
        "key1": "KeyValue1",
        "key2": "KeyValue2",
        "key3": "KeyValue3",
        .....
        "keyN": "KeyValueN"
    }
}
```

In C#, that is implemented with the use of a `Dictionary`. In Delphi, `TDictionary` or `TObjectDictionary` when serialized, extracts all the members of the class and produces a different and invalid structure.

I have tried to use `REST.JsonReflect` and create a custom `JsonReflectAttribute` and `TJSONInterceptor` and implement `ObjectConverter` in order to edit the final `TJSONObject` and add the pairs dynamically.

The following code intercepts and converts the dictionary to `TJSONObject`, which also extracts an invalid structure, because it is serialized as a class.

```pascal
uses System.Rtti, Rest.Json, System.Generics.Collections, Rest.JsonReflect;

type
  TDictionaryInterceptor = class(TJSONInterceptor)
  public
    function ObjectConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): TObject; override;
  end;
  
  function TDictionaryInterceptor.ObjectConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): TObject;
    function DictionaryToJsonObject(ADictionary: TDictionary<string, string>): TJSONObject;
    var
        JsonObject: TJSONObject;
        KeyValuePair: TPair<string, string>;
    begin
        JsonObject := TJSONObject.Create;
        try
            for KeyValuePair in ADictionary do
            begin
              JsonObject.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create(TJSONString.Create(TValue.From<string>(KeyValuePair.Key).ToString),
                                                  TJSONString.Create(TValue.From<string>(KeyValuePair.Value).ToString))
              );
            end;
            Result := JsonObject;
        finally
        end;
    end;
  var
    ctx: TRttiContext;
    Dict: TObjectDictionary<string, string>;
    RttiProperty: TRttiProperty;
  begin
    RttiProperty := ctx.GetType(Data.ClassInfo).GetProperty(Copy(Field, 2, MAXINT));
    Dict := TObjectDictionary<string, string>(RttiProperty.GetValue(Data).AsObject);

    Result := DictionaryToJsonObject(Dict);
  end;
      
  DictionaryReflectAttribute = class(JsonReflectAttribute)
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;
    
  constructor DictionaryReflectAttribute.Create;
  begin
    inherited Create(ctObject, rtObject, TDictionaryInterceptor);
  end;
  
  TExample = class
  public
    [DictionaryReflectAttribute]
    dictionary: TObjectDictionary<string, string>;
  end;
```

Is this the correct direction, or is there an alternative way to serialize `TDictionary` in the form of the example?

Comment: https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/blob/master/src/core/mormot.core.collections.pas features direct JSON serialization of its `IKeyValue<Key,Value>` dictionary (and also binary serialization and a lot of other features). It is more likely to use records and arrays for its nested data, rather than classes, but it is something worth considering.   Or you can use a `TDocVariant` storage from https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/blob/master/src/core/mormot.core.variants.pas which has a lot of methods to process any kind of unfixed JSON and search/filter within, with no class/record involved.

Comment: @mORMauthor thank you for your info. I will lookout for an example. 
I was hoping that i could use delphi's native library, and avoid to learn a new framework due to lack of time. 
I use classes as equivalent to C#, in order to avoid structuring manually a TJSONObject.
Building a TJSONObject is actually my workaround in situation with dynamic JSON, but it is not elegant, and i look for a better solution.